# c# Choosing Between Properties and Methods

Tags: c#

After reading this [microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx) about when to use properties and methods, I'm a little bit confused.

At the example at the bottom they say:

> The following code example shows a complete application that assumes
>   that a property access is computationally inexpensive. The
>   EmployeeData class incorrectly defines a property that returns a copy
>   of an array.

specifically

> The EmployeeData class incorrectly defines a property that returns a
>   copy of an array.

What would be the right way to do it?

*[fiddle of the example code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sjUAkA)*

Comment: Hazarding a guess without reading the article: The copy could be expensive, and deserves a method (implies some work to be done) instead of a property (implies only data access). The property should return a reference to the array (if this is even appropriate), not a copy of it.

Comment: Expand that text with "So it should use a method instead".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guideline, but your properties should be as lightweight as possible. Copying an array, just like in the example, is quite expansive for a property. It should be a method. This way, anyone using this code knows it could take a bit of time. Properties usually reflect accessors for private fields, so people expect it to return almost immediately. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It just clicked, the right way would be remove the Employees get property and always call the CopyEmployeeRecords() so other developers know it's an 'expensive' function to call?

Comment: @SvenB Exactly! It doesn't really change anything except tell someone this could be computationally intensive (more than just returning a field)

Answer (score 1):

The property is "incorrect" because the code inside it is slow.

```
public EmployeeRecord[] Employees
{
    get 
    {
        return CopyEmployeeRecords();   // slow code in property - bad
    }
}
```

Instead, write a method:

```
public EmployeeRecord[] Employees()
{
    return CopyEmployeeRecords();       // slow code in method - ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The section

> use a method, rather than a property, in the following situations.

in the article you were reading tells you to use a method instead of a property of the property returns an array.

So the right way to do this would be creating a method to copy the array.